# Send a file to Google Search by Image search from the Windows Explorer context menu

Tags: windows-7, google-apps

I am looking for a program that can send a file to Google image search from the Windows Explorer context menu to perform a [Search by Image](http://www.google.com/insidesearch/features/images/searchbyimage.html). If possible, free, works with Windows 7, and launch a search on Google Chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For most Image formats you already have the necessary software:

1. Open Chrome
2. From Explorer drag the file to Chrome
3. Right Click and select Search Google for this Image

You could also right click in Explorer and Select Open With then pick Chrome.  I suggest not using over large files and remember that any such request **will** have to upload the image, at least temporarily, so there may be copyright or IP issues.

Comment: Thanks but `right click in Explorer and Select Open With then pick Chrome` just open the image instead of searching for it :/

Comment: **Once Opened** right click and search for!

Comment: Thanks good point, yes I guess it's almost as fast as having an option right in the Windows Explorer context menu.

Comment: Only 1 extra click.  Otherwise you could use a python script to convert the file to a base64 string and to open the URL https://www.google.co.uk/search?tbs=sbi:*base64string* then associate that with Image types in the registry but unless you are doing this a **lot** it seems like a lot of work to avoid 1 click.

Answer (score 4):

This is quite late, but I wrote a very simple program which does this: [GoogleImageShell](https://github.com/apsun/GoogleImageShell). It adds a shortcut to the right-click menu on images (JPG, PNG, GIF, BMP) which uploads the image to Google and opens the search results in your browser.

It runs on Windows 7 and up, and requires .NET 4.6.1. The program is free and open-source; you can download a binary version [here](https://github.com/apsun/GoogleImageShell/releases).

[image]

Comment: this was exactly what I needed. It works well. Thanks!